# SQL transactional replication find force_invalidate_snapshot is 1 or zero for all article

Tags: sql-server, transactional-replication

Is there any way to find SQL transactional replication @force_invalidate_snapshot is 1 or zero for
all article?

Just wanted to know or find number of tables before I run EXEC sp_refreshsubscriptions and start snapshot job.